# Validate or Ratify?

Tags: meaning

Is there a clear difference between the "validation" or "ratification" of a document.?
I came across a document that stated "Form for the Validation & Ratification of...."  I thought that to valide & to ratify basically meant the same thing?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. As you may have learned from the [site tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help), we ask that you demonstrate some preliminary research— which dictionaries did you consult and what do their definitions of *validation* and *ratification* say? Who is the author of the document and what are they attempting to validate and ratify?

Answer (score 1):

Validation and ratification have distinct definitions.  From the free dictionary:

> [Validate](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/validate):  to make valid; substantiate; confirm.
>
> [Ratify](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/ratify):  To approve and give formal sanction to; confirm.

In other words, to "validate" a document is verify that it is true and complete.  To "ratify" a document is to give it formal approval.  These are loose synonyms through the different definitions of "confirm".

In your case, I would assume that your form is asking you to both confirm the veracity of and formally approve for submission whatever it is you are submitting.